# HomeGroup over a local area connection

Tags: windows-7, homegroup, internet-sharing

My network configuration is as follows:

- One desktop is connected by a network cable to the wireless router
- My laptop is connected to the Internet by WiFi (2nd floor)
- The laptop shares the Internet connection with my second desktop via a network cable (2nd floor)

My laptop and the desktop connected by cable to the wireless router are sharing files via a HomeGroup, yet I would like the second desktop to join in.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be hooked into the same network (physically through router or over wifi).

You could also buy another router and set it up as a bridge to the other router and you can plug your 2nd desktop into the router.  This is quite trivial if you set up the second router with DD-WRT (custom firmware for the router).

Comment: You've answered my question - it can't be done via a HomeGroup. For a workaround see http://superuser.com/questions/266949/why-cant-i-share-files-between-these-two-computers