# Why can't I share files between these two computers?

Tags: file-sharing, lan

My network configuration is as follows:

- One desktop is connected by a network
  cable to the wireless router
- My
  laptop is connected to the Internet
  by WiFi (2nd floor)
- The laptop shares
  the Internet connection with my
  second desktop via a network cable
  (2nd floor)

I'm able to share folders between the first desktop and my laptop using Windows 7's HomeGroup. However, how can I share folders between the laptop and the second desktop? It seems that using the [HomeGroup won't work for this configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/266075/homegroup-over-a-local-area-connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work for this configuration - the homegroup cannot span more than one network segment, and you have 2 segments here.

Try browsing on your upstairs desktop to the IP address of the downstairs machine prefixed with \\ in the start menu's *search* box.  Say the downstairs PC has IP address 192.168.0.53 you would use:

```
\\192.168.0.53
```

And the resultant window should contain the shares.

You won't be able to go the other way as your laptop is in the way.

Comment: Thank you for a simple and elegant solution that worked :)